# How do you manage multithreading in Xamarin.Forms app? What are the methods used to ensure it is managed properly

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Can any one give some examples how to manage multi threading in Xamarin.Forms App and check whether the mutli-threading is managed properly using any of the methods?

Answer (score 0):

This may get deleted so hopefully it gets to you if and when it does.

There’d be a lot to cover with an answer to your question so the easiest way to get across some of the important points would be to watch this video.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Brandon-Minnick-asyncawait-best-practices

I hope that helps.